# Cake php on netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans, cakephp-3.0

Am new to cakephp, but not php or MVC.

anyone knows why I get those errors?? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZtT7.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could try to change the file permission for the `tmp` folder. What OS are you on?

Try this: `chmod(path_to_tmp, 0777);`.